# Why does my webrequest line need updating? (error (426) Upgrade Required )

Tags: c#, api

I am making a `WebRequest` on a WCF service application in Visual Studio. This piece of code was working like 2 days ago and now I get this error.

I have tried updating the api key.

```
public List<string> GetData(string topic)
{
        // formats the url properly
        string beginning = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=";
        string ending = "&from=2019-09-14&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=ce1ad5bceee84d958dd9ca5bc72488a";
        string mid = topic.Replace(" ", "+");
        string url = beginning + mid + ending;

        // to hold the article urls
        List<string> all_urls = new List<string>();

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            String rawJSON = webClient.DownloadString(url);
            var newsAnchor = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< RootObject >(rawJSON);
            foreach (Article urs in newsAnchor.articles)
            {
                all_urls.Add(urs.url); 
            }
        }

        return all_urls;
}
```

The compiler returns this error:

> System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (426) Upgrade Required.'

on the line containing

```
string rawJSON = webClient.....
```

Comment: "The HTTP 426 Upgrade Required client error response code indicates that the server refuses to perform the request using the current protocol but might be willing to do so after the client upgrades to a different protocol. The server sends an Upgrade header with this response to indicate the required protocol(s)." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/426 | So Upgrade is a misnomer. "Wrong Protocoll" is the proper term.

Comment: Also this is not a compiler error, but a runtime exception, that is shown in teh Debugger Window. The difference is massive but luckily easy to spot. The missing information should be in the full exception details. Hopefully at least.

Comment: @Christopher I tried opening the full exception detail. but it just repeats the same error which i posted. Not sure how to fix this, or what exactly to "upgrade"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer. In your line of code where you put the `apiKey`, change the date to be no further back than exactly one month prior to today. E.g., since today is the 12th of May 2020, the date in the code should not be before the 12th of April 2020. I hope this helps.

```
from
    'http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=' +
         searchTerm + '&from= '''2020-04- 10'''&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=967d749e88694f2088bd47900f907bc4';

to

     'http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=' +
          searchTerm + '&from= '''2020-04-12''' &sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=967d749e88694f2088bd47900f907bc4';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see the problem if you examine the returned content.

This is what I got from

```
https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=xxx&from=2019-09-14&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=my_temp_key
```

```
status  "error"
code    "parameterInvalid"
message "You are trying to request results too far in the past. Your plan permits you to request articles as far back as 2019-09-20, but you have requested 2019-09-14. To extend this please upgrade to a paid plan."
```

Comment: Fully reading the actual error / message being returned always helps! :-)

Comment: @marc_s I would not put it past WebException or its inner exception to not properly expose that. | However I am not 100% sure it is the same error actually. I fear like this exception should fall under 400 - Bad Request. But of course you know know with some random, written WebService on the internet.